# View is not mapping the Model. Getting Model Item passed error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

**The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Vidly.Models.Customer', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Vidly.ViewModels.RandomMovieViewModel'.**

Hi,

Iam trying to load another view on click of a link which is generated by ActionLink.

The code snippets are as shown below :

```
  public class MoviesController : Controller
{


    public ActionResult CustomerDetail(int? id)
    {
        var customerRepo = new CustomerRepo();
        var selectedCustomer = customerRepo.GetCustomer().SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        return View(selectedCustomer);
    }
}
```

Now The action link are generated in a view which as shown below :

```html
@model Vidly.ViewModels.RandomMovieViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Random";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Customers</h2>
@if (Model.Customers.Count == 0)
{
    <p>No one rented the movie</p>
}

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Customer
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>


        @foreach (var customer in Model.Customers)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>

                    @Html.ActionLink(customer.Name, "CustomerDetail", "Movies", new { id = customer.Id }, null)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This calls for a CustomerDetail view which is as below :

```html
@model Vidly.Models.Customer
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CustomerDetail";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>@Model.Name</h2>
```

I have created a repository class for getting the data, currently iam putting hard coded data.

```
public class CustomerRepo
{
    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomer()
    {
        return new List<Customer>
        {
            new Customer {Id=1,Name="Rishabh" },
            new Customer {Id=2,Name="Keerti" }
        };
    }
}
```

ViewModel Class :

```
 public class RandomMovieViewModel
{
    public List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

}
```

**The issue is i am getting below error. I am passing the Customer object in view, I have also mapped the Details view with the Customer model but i don't know why it asks for me to give it ViewModel**

[image]

Comment: Does the Exception occur when browsing to the `CustomerDetail` link? Also the order of your code above makes it look like you pass `Customer` to a view that expects `RandomMovieViewModel`. This might just be a copy/paste issue however.

Comment: Certainly your controller passed `List<Customer>` collection to a view which bounds to viewmodel `Vidly.ViewModels.RandomMovieViewModel`. Show the structure of `RandomMovieViewModel` to give some details.

Comment: yup, the error comes when browse to **CustomerDetail** view.
I have put the **RandomViewModel**.

**I am not passing any collection in view attached to CustomerDetail, iam passing Customer object and that is what i have mapped in CustomerDetail view.**